# find wrong cases of assignment in the if-else

Tags: c, regex, if-statement

What is the regular expression to identify attribution error out instead of comparison within a validation "if-else"?
wrong cases:

```
if ( var1 = var2 )
if ( var1= var2 )
if ( var1 =var2 )
if ( var1=var2 )
```

Correct cases:

```
if ( var1 == var2 )
if ( var1== var2 )
if ( var1 ==var2 )
if ( var1==var2 )
```

Comment: Visual Studio 6,  Notepad++, http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed -n '/if *( *[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]* *= *[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*/p'
```

Comment: this way help me : ([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]* *= *[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]) using in http://regexpal.com/. Tanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if *\( *var1 *=[^=]* *var2 *\)
```

Answer (score 0):

`if\s*\([^=]*=[^=]*\)` using [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/D3Y7GLz2Le)